# Python forestci.random_forest_error return negative value

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, random-forest, prediction-interval

After running a out sample prediction using randomforestregressor, I need to construct a confidence interval for the predictions. The rational behind it is to give the business side a sense of what the best scenario would be and what the worst scenario could be.

I used the package forest_confidence_interval from here: http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/forest-confidence-interval/
Everything runs fine but the unbiased variance for the predicted value is negative for the majority of the observations.

Some of the feature data is very sparse. Some of the feature data have long tails. The target variable is sales data which naturally has long tail.

I tried to increase the number of trees to reduce noise, but it hasn't worked so far. (from 500 to 5000 trees).

Does anyone have experience with this methodology / package and know how to fix this?

Thanks!

BTW, change method is not available for various reasons. Have to stick with RF.

Code I use is here:

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=5000, n_jobs=-1, max_features=0.5, verbose=1, min_samples_leaf=3, oob_score=False, random_state=793682)

rf.fit(c_train[f_cols],c_train[target[j]])

pred_test=rf.predict(c_test[f_cols])

v_unbiased = fci.random_forest_error(rf, c_train[f_cols], c_test[f_cols])
```

Comment: Have you figured out an answer to this? Can't we just take the absolute value of unbiased variance and compute the square root of errors?